# How can I export a DOM ancestor list in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to determine whether an element is inside more than one (nested) iframe. If I inspect an element I get a breadcrumb trail of sorts at the bottom of the inspector pane:

[image]

Sometimes this ancestor list is very long and it's difficult to scroll through it to analyze the structure. How can I export or otherwise capture this list?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to use **devtools-on-devtools** to get that data from devtools UI:

1. switch to `Elements` panel
2. open **devtools-on-devtools** (see below) and run this in console: `console.log($$('devtools-node-text', UI.panels.elements._breadcrumbs.shadowRoot).map(el => $$('span', el.shadowRoot).map(el => el.innerText).join('')).join('\n'))`

   It'll print text like this:

   ```
   html.html__responsive.html__unpinned-leftnav
   body.question-page.unified-theme
   div.container
   div#content.snippet-hidden
   ```

   The actual data is stored in `UI.panels.elements._breadcrumbs` and its various properties.

   As an example of fancying it up:

   ```js
   (() => {
     let num = 0;
     const args = [];
     const root = UI.panels.elements._breadcrumbs.shadowRoot;
     $$('devtools-node-text', root).forEach(bc => {
       num++;
       let info = '';
       $$('span', bc.shadowRoot).map(({innerText: s}, i) => {
         if (!i) {
           args.push(`font-weight:bold;${s === 'iframe' ? 'color:red;' : ''}`, s,
             'font-weight:normal');
         } else {
           info += s;
         }
       });
       args.push(info);
     });
     console.log('%c%s%c%s\n'.repeat(num), ...args);
   })();
   ```

   [image]

---

For convenience you can save the code in [snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) and run it later from there or by typing the snippet name in the commands palette (<kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-P</kbd> hotkey).

#### How to open devtools-on-devtools:

1. Open devtools first and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window